# Moving from TFS to Git or Mercurial strategy?

Tags: git, tfs, migration

I have googled and searched this site and I am not finding anything really helpful that makes me feel confident in its method for this migration.

Currently the company is using TFS, when I got here I planned on moving us to Git or similar so I worked on grouping all of our projects into a single branch since they were scattered all over. Now we have a setup like this.

```
Root
---|Releases
-------|Dev
-------|Test
-------|Main
---|Features
-------|Feature1
-------|Feature2
```

Main is our production branch and is the most refined and clean working code, test and dev are less refined of course. They all hold the same set of application folders in them though.

The features folder holds branches for feature development, so basically they are branched from Dev modified and then we merge them back into dev when completed.

I wanted to know what the best method is for migrating our source control to Git or Mecurial.

I was thinking about copying Main to the master origin, then creating a branch from it and copying test into that folder over writing everything, and then branch test into a dev branch and do the same thing. Then leaving the feature branches alone and losing whatever was in them or letting the devs create their own branch to merge them over.

Is there a better way of doing this that will help keep history to some extent? If not, does the method described above seem like it will work? My concern is when I branch Main and then copy the files from Test over the files in the test branch it will lose its relationship or be unable to determine the changes affectively.  Any thoughts?

I found this, but I am unsure of how I would use it to take my existing TFS setup and move it into the git repository with the setup I have mentioned above.

http://gittf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Your layout seems to resemble the space partitioning of the branches, not the time partitioning. Does it mean that there is a release branch where dev, test and main branches away from? Or does it just mean that you grouped those 3 branches under the "releases" umbrella?

Answer (score 0):

The Team Foundation Server seems to have native GIT support in it's 2013 version. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server#Source_Control

This looks like an easy task: Update your version, then use GIT. Done.

Comment: Yeah, not really that easy. We also probably wont be using their git repository. You cant just flip between the repositories. I see TFS2Git and git-tfs scripts but not sure if they would work for my situation and was hoping to get some more information on the process.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy answer to your questions. What I would have done thougis a clean cut on a weekend in releation to a switch between sprints. I would have made everyone check in what they got before the weekend, and then I would have merged everything from Dev to Test and used this as the main trunk in my new Git repository. From the Trunk in Git I would have created the necessary feature branches and release branches.

In a feature branch scheme you shouln't need both Dev and feature brances. You test everything in the Trunk whenever the feature branches integrates their code. Then you create release branches from the trunk whenever you need to stabilize or Acceptance Test a release.

- Trunk

  - Feature 1
  - Feature 2
  - Feature 3
  - Release Sprint 10
  - Release Sprint 11

etc.

In my approach you wont preserve any history, and you will have to maintain your release branches (emergency patching etc) in TFS for a while, but I think it is the cleanest way and you will have new, fresh relations between the folders. The history can be looked up in TFS, so just lock for checkin in all brances (Except maybe Main if you need to do emergency patches etc) so that you don't risk people checking stuff in as an old habit.

Good luck, no matter which approach you take.

btw: if you haven't decided on new SCM, take a look at PlasticSCM. This has the branching/merging flexibility of Git, and the visual tools that will match TFS.